# ContentControl visibility binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have a visibility binding like this inside a UserControl.

```
<Grid x:Name="_dockPanelMain">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Member=consts:RegionNames.MainMenu}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Visibility="{Binding MainMenuVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"/> 
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dockManagerModules" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Member=consts:RegionNames.Modules}" Visibility="{Binding ModulesVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="dockManagerStatusBar" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static Member=consts:RegionNames.StatusBar}"/>
</Grid>
```

This user control is given a ViewModel, of which relevant part is

```
        private void SwitchMenuAndModulViews(object sender)
    {
        if (ModulesVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            ModulesVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            MainMenuVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            ModulesVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MainMenuVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

        private Visibility _modulesVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
    public Visibility ModulesVisibility
    {
        get { return _modulesVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _modulesVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(() => ModulesVisibility);
        }
    }

    private Visibility _mainMenuVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    public Visibility MainMenuVisibility
    {
        get { return _mainMenuVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _mainMenuVisibility = value;
            RaisePropertyChangedEvent(() => MainMenuVisibility);
        }
    }
```

When SwitchMenuAndModulView gets called, nothing happens. The variables change, but the binding does not work and both ContentControls have Visibility set as Visible at all times, which I guess is the default and none of them ever change to Collapsed.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:

I solved it myself, the problem was not in the binding itself but in the way the application dealt with instantiating and showing the UserControl.

I had an instance of a UserControl A that had this UserControl B as a part of its content. Naturaly, A created an instance of B upon its creation. 
Later, I replaced the instance of B in A by a different instance of B (the one with my viewModel) but I probably forgot to tell the visual tree about the change, therefore visualy it still showed the old B instance whose binding did not lead anywhere.

I kind of wish an application threw an exception when a blind binding happens (as in, it binds to an element that is either not instantiated or misspelled) instead of just leaving the default there. This behaviour of XAML generates so many bugs.